# evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{A(x^{2n}-1)+1}$

Tags: summation

i tried a few thing but none them worked out so I'm totally clueless what to do to solve this $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{A(x^{2n}-1)+1}$$

Comment: What is $A$? ${}$

Comment: ...and what is $\,x\,$ ...?

Comment: their both constant numbers so i think the answer should be in the form of $$F(x,A)$$

Comment: The ratio of terms is:

$$ a_{n+1}/a_n = x\frac {Ax^{2n} -A +1} {Ax^{2n+2}-A +1}.$$

If $|x|\leq1$, this goes to $x$. If $|x|>1$, this goes to $1/x$. Therefore it converges by the ratio test for all $x$, $|x|\neq 1$. We test at $x = 1, -1$. By inspection, it diverges for these. So it converges exactly on $$\{x : |x|\neq 1 \}.$$

Comment: This question is a valid and interesting one. The partial sums of this series can be expressed in closed form in terms of the $q$-polygamma function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). Then probably the sum can be computed taking limits. I am not familiar with these functions but some around here are and will give a solution from which we will all learn something interesting. There is no need for patronizing the OP with stupid questions like what is $A$ and $x$.

Comment: @RGB, I don't think it was obvious what $A$ was. (I thought it was a function at first, until the OP corrected us.)

Comment: oh, that is right. My apologies to Chonoles.

Answer (score 0):

**This is only a bit of unjustified information**

It seems to be (by experimenting with different values of $A$) that the partial sums ($\sum_{n=1}^{m}$) of the series are

$-\frac{\psi_{x}\left(m-\frac{i\pi-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{A}{A-1})}{\ln(x)}+1\right)}{2\sqrt{A(A-1)}\ln(x)}+\frac{\psi_{x}\left(m-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{A}{A-1})}{\ln(x)}+1\right)}{2\sqrt{A(A-1)}\ln(x)}+\frac{\psi_{x}\left(1-\frac{i\pi-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{A}{A-1})}{\ln(x)}+1\right)}{2\sqrt{A(A-1)}\ln(x)}-\frac{\psi_{x}\left(1-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{A}{A-1})}{\ln(x)}+1\right)}{2\sqrt{A(A-1)}\ln(x)}$

where $\psi_{q}(z)$ is the [$q$-polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). For those familiar with playing with these functions this may help/give an idea, perhaps.

I experimented with the summation starting from $n=1$ by mistake. The difference is just the first term anyway.